# capturing groups regex with cuantifiers

Tags: pandas, regex-group

I'm using pandas.Series.str.extract function to extract year and quarter from strings. But I can not make to do it correctly.

These are the strings that are in series.

```
Divvy_Stations_2013
Divvy_Stations_2014-Q1Q2
Divvy_Stations_2014-Q3Q4
Divvy_Stations_2015
Divvy_Stations_2016_Q1Q2
Divvy_Stations_2016_Q3
Divvy_Stations_2016_Q4
Divvy_Stations_2017_Q1Q2
Divvy_Stations_2017_Q3Q4
```

My best regex try it got these match, previously I tried to use quantifiers with groups but I only got nans in both column.

`tables['origin'].drop_duplicates().str.extract(pat=r'.*(\d{4}).*(Q[1-4]).*')`

It is almost ok but in the first and fourth rows I only got nans. I know that these strings doesn't contain Q\d. So, is fine get "nan" in that column but not "nan"  in years column.

```
NaN     NaN
2014    Q2
2014    Q4
NaN     NaN
2016    Q2
2016    Q3
2016    Q4
2017    Q2
2017    Q4
```

Comment: Those strings don't match the pattern because there's no `.*(Q...` If you want to match both versions you have to make that part optional, `(Q[1-4])?` I think

Comment: @zapl I already did that. The Q/d column gets nan in all the rows. But years column got all the correct values.

Comment: @zapl OK, I found already the solution. But I don't know why this works.... the solution is `'.*(\d{4}).?(Q[1-4])?.*'`, so adding the `?` after the group and replace the second `*` by `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is replace the second `*` by `?` and adding a `?` after the second group.

originally I had:

`'.*(\d{4}).*(Q[1-4]).*'`

and the solution is:

`'.*(\d{4}).?(Q[1-4])?.*'`

Previously I used this: `'.*(\d{4}).*(Q[1-4])?.*'` but did't work. Why replacing the `*` by `?` works? the description of `*` say "Zero o more times" and the description of `?` says "Once or none".

Does `none` is different of `Zero` in regex language?